# What GTK+ sub-process/threading/program execution/etc should I use if I want to launch a program from a GTK+ app?

Tags: multithreading, gtk, glib, gdk, gio

If I wanted to run, say `stty`, which controls the terminal settings ( like character by character, or line by line), what would be the best way to do this. I want to use GTK+ tools. Would it be better to create a new thread, then run the program from that...or...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there are 7 functions in the GTK+ API that do the specs you listed. 2 of those are subsets of a couple of them. Here is the list.

```
g_spawn_
g_thread_ 
g_task_
g_subprocess_
gdk_threads_
```

The last one belongs to GDK (Gimp Drawing Kit (why does it have threading?)), and the rest to GIO and Glib. Here are the subsets of `g_thread_` and `g_subprocess_`:

```
g_thread_pool_
g_subprocess_launcher_
```

You failed to identify in the question above whether or not you wanted `stty` run independent of the app, or, so to put it, connected to the app.

I am now going to run through all the functions mentioned above, and explain their use. As always, check the GTK+ documentation for API Reference information. A good program that shows the GTK+ docs is `devhelp`. You can install it by typing in the terminal: `sudo apt install devhelp`. (Linux)

`g_spawn_` is a Glib function used as a more convenient version of the UNIX `fork` and `exec` functions. It has limited communication with the process. In some cases this is what you want, namely running a program whose output does not really have to be scanned. For a more advanced version of this, check out `g_subprocess_`.

`g_thread_` belongs to Glib also. The difference between a (sub)process and a thread is that threads share the same address space, whereas a (sub)process does not (they have their own memory). It is good to use threads because it is very easy to communicate between them, but you have to be careful, otherwise Heisenbugs will show up. This function supports mutex-es (plural), preventing race conditions. An example of a program that would use threads would be a image editor. One thread handles the mouse movements, the other handles the applying of effects, the other writes autosave information every minute or so.

`g_thread_pool_` is exactly the same as `g_thread_` except that is has built-in handling of many threads. A browser, such as Chromium or Opera, would use this function if written in GTK+. Each thread would handle one tab, and then there would by a master thread, which would manage (destroy and create, etc.) the sub-threads.

`g_task_` represents a task to do. It is generally asynchronous, but it can be synchronous. You call `g_task_new()` and given that it is asynchronous, the code that called the function containing `g_task_new()` will resume. You indicate that the task is done by calling the `g_task_return_` family of functions. Then the callback function is invoked, and that is the end. This has essentially the same use as a separate thread, which when it is destroyed, a callback is invoked.

`g_subprocess_` is a more convenient, sophisticated version of `g_spawn_`. The major advantage it has over the Glib spawning is its capabilities for asynchronous I/O: you can read from the output of one subprocess, and process the output, then send to the input stream of another process, without blocking the main loop. This is possible with `g_spawn_` and other APIs, but is more difficult.

`gdk_threads_` is essentially the same as the Glib version. The only difference is on the automatic locking of individual data structure instances. `g_thread_` does not do this for performance reasons. But you can lock them manually with `g_thread_` whereas with `gdk_threads_` it is done automatically. But because `g_thread_` has more documentation, it is better to use it.

So, the answer to your question is to use `g_spawn_`. It is the simplest, and when you write a program you try to keep everything simple.

Comment: Why are you answering your own question in the second person? Is this answer copied from an answer given to you by someone else, elsewhere? If so, it would be polite to credit them.

Comment: No, I came up with this all by myself and using the GTK+ documentation.

Comment: I used the second person 'cause I am not sure what person to use. What do you suggest: First person?

Comment: Yeah, and explicitly stating that you’re answering your own question based on having done further research helps make things clearer :)